# "Standort Deutschland"

Tags: meaning

Mir ist trotz Blicks in Wörterbücher nicht wirklich klar, was "Standort" heißen soll in der Wendung "Standort Deutschland". Kann man zum Beispiel in den folgenden Setzen "Standort" auch anders ausdrücken?

> Es geht darum, eine ausgewogene
>   Balance zwischen den Zielen der
>   Energiewende und der Sicherung
>   **des Standorts Deutschland** zu schaffen.
>
> **Der Standort Deutschland** gehört einer Studie zufolge nicht mehr zu den zehn wettbewerbsfähigsten der Welt.

Comment: Und was verstehst du an dem Begriff nicht? Also, was genau ist deine Frage?

Comment: Bitte lese erst das hier: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standort_Deutschland, wenn es Fragen darüber hinaus gibt, dann immer her damit.

Comment: Den Artikel habe ich schon 3 Mal gelesen, trotzdem wird mir nicht klar, was es genau damit auf sich hat. Deswegen bitte ich mit dieser Frage um eine einfache Antwort, soweit das natürlich möglich ist.

Comment: Deine Frage ist also, was genau ein "Wirtschaftsstandort" ist?

Comment: @Annatar Vielmehr die Kombination "Standort Deutschland", aber der von Dir genannte Begriff hat sicherlich nahezu dieselbe Bedeutung

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der Standort bezieht sich auf die Bedeutung für ein Unternehmen, in Deutschland ansässig zu sein. Welche Steuern muss es zahlen, welche Mitarbeiter stehen zur Verfügung (wie qualifiziert sind sie, welche Gehälter sind zu zahlen), welche Umweltauflagen müssen beachtet werden, oder wie groß ist die Bürokratie. Diese Liste lässt sich beliebig fortzusetzen und bezieht Vor- wie Nachteile ein.

Folgende Floskel wird gerne von Wirtschaftsvertretern verwendet, wenn sie ausdrücken wollen, daß die Politik zu arbeitnehmerfreundlich sei:

> Ich befürchte, der Standort Deutschland ist in Gefahr.

Answer (score 2):

"Standort Deutschland" heißt:

> Deutschland als Ort, wo Unternehmen wirtschaftlich tätig sind

(Ja, es war eigentlich schon beantwortet, aber ich wollte ausnahmsweise mal eine richtig kurze Antwort schreiben, und hier sah ich die Chance.)

Comment: Danke immerhin für die gute Antwort